# ImageButton resizes when I change background

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I am making my first android app in Android Studio. I have an `ImageButton` that I want to change on click. For that I made a new class called `Field` that extends `ImageButton` class. so, I use that instead of `ImageButton`. And in the class field I redefined a constructor so that I added that it sets `OnClickListener` when it creates `Field` object.

Here is Java code I used for that: `

```
public Field(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Field(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public Field(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
        }
    });
}`
```

Than, when I create `Field` object in my activity, `OnClickListener` is set. 
And, it works. However, the new image called `open` is bigger that my previous image called `pic01`, but both images have the same size `185x185`.

Here is my activity xml:

```
<asd.clicker.Field
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/asd.clicker.Field1"
    android:background="@drawable/pic01"
    android:layout_above="@+id/asd.clicker.Field4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />
```

I noticed that, even when I just change `pic01` to `open` in my xml, the `open` image is bigger than `pic01`, both are `.png`. How can I get image of the same size when I click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the two lines

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

or some other size you wan't your view to have. `wrap_content` will change the view's size based on the displayed drawable.